# HttpClient Request return 200 OK even for non valid urls

Tags: c#, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

I'm validating urls, I'm having an issue with my code, I'm receiving a 200 OK response even when the url is not valid. This is my code:

```
            var urlFormatted = "http://sfgsfgsg";
            Uri uri;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(urlFormatted, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            {
                return Json(new { error = "Please enter a valid url" });
            }
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {                    
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(urlFormatted);
                string textResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return Json(new { response = "success" });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { error = "Please enter a valid url" });
                }
            }
```

I took a look to the variable `textResult` value and what I'm getting is a search query from a Default Search Engine in Internet? This is the `textResult` value: `"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=http://search.frontier.com/search/?q=http://sfgsfgsg%2F&bc=\"/></head><body><script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location=\"http://search.frontier.com/search/?q=\"+escape(window.location)+\"&r=\"+escape(document.referrer)+\"&bc=\";</script></body></html>"`

How can I get a 404 and prevent that behavior? I'm not having problems when the url is valid.

Screenshot of request response:
[image]

Comment: What is value for `client.BaseAddress` ?

Comment: I wounder if it is because of the header you add. Try removing that.

Comment: @Michael it was happening before I added the header too

Comment: I cant reproduce your results  https://dotnetfiddle.net/fbcnzM

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Looks like that is DNS-based search service redirect that happens on the Router or some Firewall server. Do you get the same result in the regular browser? Possible solution - setup external DNS in the network connection properties e.g. 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS)

Comment: @aepot you're right, once I push an update to the development site it's working properly, not sure what I need to do to run it locally from Visual Studio though, but yup, it looks like is related to what you describe